# JSON with Bytes : TypeError: 'abc' has type <class 'str'>, but expected one of: (<class 'bytes'>,)

Tags: python, json, api, rest, postman

I have bytes in the JSON body as the data inputs. I don't know how else to format in JSON so the API will take it. Part of the API function will take the bytes input and serialized through base64 in order for the TensorFlow model can return the prediction, which is the output of the API.

**TypeError: 'abc' has type <class 'str'>, but expected one of: (<class 'bytes'>,)**

**Parsing Body**

```
{
    "cc": "b'abc'",
    "pt": "b'def'",
    "project": "xxx",
    "model": "xxx",
    "signature": "xxx",
    "version": "xxx"
}
```

the bytes input is to pass through the following function to serialize through Base64, in order for the tensorflow to return prediction.

```
def get_serialized_example(raw):
    return tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(
            feature={"value":
                         tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[raw]))
                     }
        )
    ).SerializeToString()

b64_country_code = base64.b64encode(get_serialized_example(request.country_code)).decode('utf-8')
b64_project_type = base64.b64encode(get_serialized_example(request.project_type)).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: We’re going to need more information than this. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I've updated my post/. @AMC

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you may have a syntax issue with your JSON content. It should be formatted something like this:

> {
>
> "cc": "b'abc'",
> "pt": "b'def'",
> "project": "xxx",
> "modell": "xxx",
> "sighnature": "xxx",
> "version": "xxx"
> }

There are a ton of great tools online to assist in JSON syntax... check out [Free JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org)

Also, if you haven’t already, check out [Postman](https://www.postman.com). It’s an incredible API tool. You can manually plug in all of the relevant data, then tell it to export it as a Python script... pretty awesome!

Comment: Hi ZenDiagram! Thanks for your comment! I have changed the format accordingly, however, with the cc and pt, they needs to be bytes type. Hence, the b'abc', cause it returns the TypeError: "b'abc'" has type <class 'str'>, but expected one of: (<class 'bytes'>,)

Comment: I also added more information in the post. The function to serialize data input in order for the model to return prediction.

Comment: TypeError: 'abc' has type <class 'str'>, but expected one of: (<class 'bytes'>,)

Comment: Gotcha, ok. Sorry, based on the initial post, it appeared the issue was JSON syntax related. Looks like someone more familiar with TensorFlow will need to assist.

Answer (score 0):

After days of experimenting, JSON format won't take the bytes class hence, I need to pass the transformation from string as data inputs to bytes as part of the function.

```
 bytes_country_code = bytes(request.country_code, 'utf-8')
 bytes_project_type = bytes(request.project_type, 'utf-8')
 b64_country_code = base64.b64encode(get_serialized_example(bytes_country_code)).decode('ascii')
 b64_project_type = base64.b64encode(get_serialized_example(bytes_project_type)).decode('ascii')
```